# Compile Error in Microsoft Access Visual Basics "Expected: list separator or)"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new to using Microsoft Visual Basics and after searching around I still can't seem to find how to resolve this Compile Error

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
PlaySound (N:\Computing\ISDD\Chime.wav)
End Sub
```

It comes up with a compile error message of "Expected: list separator or)" and highlights the colon in line 2 of the code. Apologies if this is an easy thing to fix I just can't understand where the issue is, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the API call in a module (the apisndPlaySound api call) and your wrapper function PlaySound like that:

```
Declare Function apisndPlaySound Lib "winmm" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _
    (ByVal filename As String, ByVal snd_async As Long) As Long

Public Function PlaySound(ByVal sWav As String)
    apisndPlaySound sWav, 1
End Function
```

Then on your OnOpen event you call it:

```
PlaySound "N:\..."
```

Without the parentheses, otherwise it tries to return a value back. And also the double quotes.

Comment: It doesn't come up with any errors anymore so thank you for this, it still doesn't make any sound though, is there anything else I need to change in the OnOpen event module?

Comment: Recheck that this is the right path for the wav file and that it does make a sound when you double-click on it. Of course, check your speakers too.

Comment: Also, you can try apisndPlaySound sWav, 0  with a zero instead of a 1, so that you wait for the sound to finish.

Comment: Perfect, it finally worked, thank you so much for your time and help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  PlaySound "N:\Computing\ISDD\Chime.wav"
End Sub
```

You were missing two double quotes in value.

Comment: That resolved the first issue so thank you very much for that, however it now comes up with another compile error of "Sub or Function not defined" and it highlights the "PlaySound" in line two

Comment: either you write Call PlaySound ("N:\...") or simply PlaySound "N:\"

Comment: I accenditally typed a bracket, sorry for that

Comment: Still coming up with that same error of "Sub or Function not defined" without the brackets, I've added the double quotes though

Comment: then try with double slashes: "N:\\Computing\\ISDD\\Chime.wav"

Comment: How is your PlaySound defined? is it an API call?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I check that?

Comment: right-click on it and select Definition or Go to Definition

Comment: It comes up with "Identifier under cursor is not recognized"

Comment: I edited my response above. It seems that you don't have this function. You have to declare and define it.